# Use svg objects instead of raste image object in canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, kineticjs, fabricjs

I am trying to create an application like **[this](http://www.periodontalchart-online.com/uk/)** using JavaScript and canvas.

I have created a draft using kineticjs as the canvas library. The teeth are all png images and the lines are drawn by kinetic js using the Line object.

A friend of mine suggested I draw everything as one large svg (teeth and lines) where each tooth and line is another distinguished path load it on canvas with distinguished id's and manipulate them using the id's.

I tried reading the kineticjs docs and fabricjs object but didn't find something like that. I mean having the svg stored and loading it on canvas using fabricjs or kineticjs. Then the library should parse it and create the svg on canvas which I can manipulate them by id's.

Is it even possible? I am very new to this svg graphics. Is it even possible the way I am thinking it?

I am currently loading Teeth as Images using KineticJS

```
Periodontogram.prototype.initializeImageObjects = function (){
    var obj = this;
    if (this.DEBUG){
        console.log("initializing ImageObjects:")
    }
    var check = function (item){return item !== undefined;}
    var url = this.options.url; 
    var imageObj;
    var image;

    this.options.imageFilenames.forEach(function (filename, index){
        if (obj.DEBUG){
            console.log("Loading "+filename+" image");
        }
        var src = url+'/'+filename;
        imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src  = src;
        imageObj.onload = function (){
            if (obj.DEBUG){
                console.log("Image "+src+" successfully loaded");
            }
            image = new Kinetic.Image({
                x:0,
                y:0,
                id: filename.split('.')[0],
                width: this.width,
                height: this.height,
                image:this
            });
            obj.imageObjects[index] = this;
            obj.teethImages[index] = image;
            if (obj.imageObjects.filter(check).length === obj.options.imageFilenames.length )    {
                if (obj.DEBUG){
                    console.log("All Images loaded successfully");
                    console.log("ready to call rest methods")
                }
                obj.positionImages();
                obj.createLineGroups();
                obj.createLabelGroups()
                obj.createStage();
                obj.drawOnScreen();
                $("#"+obj.container).width(obj.stage.getWidth());
                $("#"+obj.container).height(obj.stage.getHeight ());
                obj.callback();
                $.event.trigger({
                    type:'finishLoading',
                    obj: obj
                });

            }

        };

    });

}
```

I want all this be replaced by loading a whole svg, that consist of teeth and lines.

Comment: What did you try, could you share the code with us?

Comment: At the moment I use KineticJs and have everything loaded as png image used Kinetic.Image for the teeth, and Kinetic.Line for the horizontal parallel lines. I can't find anywhere how to use svg Image and manipulate parts of the svg using KineticJS or Fabric maybe. There is a lot of code right now. I could give some examples of how I load Images.

Answer (score 1):

FabricJS will **convert, decompose & recompose** an existing single SVG URL/string into a Fabric.PathGroup.  Then you can use `mySvgGroup.getObjects()` to fetch the individual tooth paths which you can manipulate as desired.

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#deserialization

KineticJS will accept an individual SVG tooth's path data and display it on canvas.

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Path.html

Still, it's probably more flexible to create individual SVG paths for each tooth and feed those individual SVGs into either KineticJS or FabricJS.

Then you can manipulate them by id's as you desire:

- Place each individual tooth using [x,y] coordinates,
- Resize without pixelization,
- Put each tooth in a Group and make annotations/drawings onto the tooth,